# VBA Excel concatenating two variable values to form a new variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that reads in multiple entities, catorgorizes and sorts them. Each entity has a type (A, B, C, etc.) that should determine what sheet it gets put into and all of them get put into my "All" sheet. Each time I find an entity of any given type I'd also like to increment a variable specific to that type.

What I'd like to do if find the type and do two things:
Set the current sheet to that type.
Set the counter variable to that type.

Example:

```
Dim x As Integer, FindSlot As Integer
Dim CurrentSheet As String, CurrentPropertyNumb As String
Dim APropertyNumb As String, BPropertyNumb As String
Dim CPropertyNumb As String

For x = 1 to 2
If x = 1 Then
    CurrentSheet = "All"
Else
    CurrentSheet = Range("B" & FindSlot)
    CurrentPropertyNumb = CurrentSheet & PropertyNumb
End If
Next x
```

In the else block, CurrentSheet will get set to "A", "B", "C" or whatever the type is. Then I'd like CurrentPropertyNumb to get set to "APropertyNumb" or "BPropertyNumb" etc. Obviously I could do this with several If statements but it would end up being 12 of them which I'd rather avoid plus I think this would be cool! :)

Is there any way to do this or am I being too lofty with my goals?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question correctly, but are you after a `Select...Case` statement? Here's an MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Comment: What's the purpose of the counter?

Comment: @DanWagner Not exactly, if I were to use Select...Case I'd end up looking for each type individually and it wouldn't save me any time/space over multiple if statements. Each type should be unique.

Comment: @TimWilliams There's actually also a bunch of print and format statements within the counter that I just didn't include. The counter is worthless in this example, sorry for the misdirect.

Comment: Then I'm really not following your question at all...  Only thing I could suggest is maybe try a `Scripting Dictionary`: that can hold values keyed to arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a series of values which you'd like to index using a string value then a Dictionary is a good fit:

```
Dim x As Integer, FindSlot As Integer
Dim CurrentSheet As String, CurrentPropertyNumb As String
Dim PropNums as Object
Dim CPropertyNumb As String

Set PropNums = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")

For x = 1 to 2
If x = 1 Then
    CurrentSheet = "All"
Else

    CurrentSheet = Range("B" & FindSlot)
    If Not PropNums.Exists(CurrentSheet) Then
        PropNums.Add CurrentSheet, 1 '? what are the initial values here?
    Else
        PropNums(CurrentSheet) = PropNums(CurrentSheet) +1
    End If
    CurrentPropertyNumb = PropNums(CurrentSheet)

End If
Next x
```